# Complicated makefile

Tags: c, makefile, lex

Most makefiles I have used in the past are very basic, using no more than a single command, such as how the clean command in the below code. Could someone please explain to me how this works? What exactly is `OBJS` and `$@`

```
# compiler to use
CC  = gcc

# object files needed for the project
OBJS    = main.o lex.yy.o error.o

# the main target
calc: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o $@ $(OBJS) -ll

# dependencies
main.o: main.c y.tab.h

error.o: error.h

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c y.tab.h

lex.yy.c: simple-arith.l
        $(LEX) simple-arith.l

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJS) lex.yy.c
```

Here is the ouput of the make command:

```
-bash-4.1$ make
gcc    -c -o main.o main.c
lex simple-arith.l
gcc    -c -o lex.yy.o lex.yy.c
gcc    -c -o error.o error.c
gcc -o calc main.o lex.yy.o error.o -ll
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: ooga is right.  At the point where you're asking _what is `OBJS`_, you should go read the manual or find an online tutorial or something.

Comment: I'm going to read more. I just couldn't tell if things such as OBJS were user defined or makefile specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OBJS` is a variable. The object files are what your compiler outputs for each compilation unit, and will be fed into the linker.

```
calc: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o $@ $(OBJS) -ll
```

That line is telling Make to rebuild calc whenever any of the files in the `$(OBJS)` variable change. `$@` is a special [Make variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) that refers to the name of the target (in this case `calc`).

What Make does is build a [dependency graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of its targets. The targets come before the `:` and the dependencies come after. If any target needs to be built (like the default `calc` in the example) it will check all of its dependencies to see if any of them need to be rebuilt. Make uses the modification time to determine this; if a target is older than one of its dependencies, or the target doesn't exist, it needs rebuilding.

Answer (score 2):

`OBJS` is just a variable: `OBJS    = main.o lex.yy.o error.o`

$@ is an Automatic Variable. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

> $@
>       The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an archive member, then ‘$@’ is the name of the archive file. In a
>   pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern
>   Rules), ‘$@’ is the name of whichever target caused the rule's recipe
>   to be run.

So in this case:

```
calc: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o $@ $(OBJS) -ll
```

$@ is "calc"